# jQuery v1.11.1 .each() use on multi level child elements

Tags: jquery, each

I need a way with jQuery or javascript (pref. jQuery) to truncate some slider descriptions.

My issues is when I run my function, it returns the first value into every . I've seen some things about using jQuery Index similar to how one would in php, but the jQuery API page doesn't explain it very well.

HTML to be trunked...

```
<div class="description">
<div class="hidden">
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a>
</div>

<div class="">
    <a href="#">consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua..</a>
</div>

<div class="hidden">
    <a href="#">sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt Lorem ipsum sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a>
</div>
```

below is my javascript..
pretened i'm using proper document ready functions and such...

```
<script>
jQuery('div.slideshow_panel > div.description > div.hidden > a').each(function(){
var desctext = jQuery('div.slideshow_panel > div.description > div > a').text();
var cuttext = desctext.substr(0,20);

jQuery( this ).append(cuttext +'...');

});


</script>
```

Thanks for your advice in advance!

Comment: `var desctext = jQuery('div.slideshow_panel > div.description > div > a').text();` should be `var desctext = jQuery(this).text();`

Comment: I'd consider setting a size on your `<div>` and using the [`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not `append()`, but replace the text.

`$(this).text(cuttext + '...');`

Also there is more clean solution for this particular task, using method `$.text()` with the callback as an argument (See [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function)).
In this way you don't need the overhead of `$.each()` and its body.

```js
$('div.slideshow_panel > div.description > div.hidden > a').text(function(index, text) {
  return text.substr(0, 20) + '...';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow_panel">
    
    <div class="description">
        
        <div class="hidden">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a>
        </div>
        <br />
            
        <div class="">
            <a href="#">consectetur adipiscing elit, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua..</a>
        </div>
        
        <br />
        <div class="hidden">
            <a href="#">sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt Lorem ipsum sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</a>
        </div>
        
    </div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've never thought about doing it this way. This is really simple.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` keyword to reference the current element and use `.text()` to replace the contents.

```
jQuery('div.slideshow_panel > div.description > div.hidden > a').each(function(){

    var desctext = jQuery(this).text(); //use 'this' keyword to get current element
    var cuttext = desctext.substr(0,20);

    jQuery(this).text(cuttext +'...'); //use .text instead to replace

});
```

Comment: Duh....I don't know why I was having such and issue yesterday. ( this ) would have solved everything. 

Also, i've never thought about using .text() in the reverse. I'll have to try that in the future. 

Previously, i would use .empty().appened() 

Thanks for your help @derek-s

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` to refer to the current element:

```
jQuery('div.slideshow_panel > div.description > div.hidden > a').each(function(){
var desctext = jQuery(this).text();
var cuttext = desctext.substr(0,20);

jQuery( this ).append(cuttext +'...');

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, this is the same answer as @derek-s